# Not able to deploy ear to websphere using deployment api

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

When I try to deploy an EAR file using deployment API, I get the below exception:

In SystemOut.log:

```
[6/23/16 16:26:16:894 IST] 00000091 HttpConnectio E   HttpConnection.run: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 0 response bytes written, but Content-Length header equals 1974
[6/23/16 16:26:16:895 IST] 000000c0 InstallSchedu I   ADMA5014E: The installation of application testDeploy failed.
```

In SystemErr.log:

```
[6/23/16 16:26:16:890 IST] 000000c0 SystemErr     R javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Unterminated key property part
[6/23/16 16:26:16:891 IST] 000000c0 SystemErr     R     at javax.management.ObjectName.construct(ObjectName.java:568)
[6/23/16 16:26:16:891 IST] 000000c0 SystemErr     R     at javax.management.ObjectName.<init>(ObjectName.java:1394)
[6/23/16 16:26:16:891 IST] 000000c0 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.application.InstallSchedulerImpl.updateAppAndCellName(InstallSchedulerImpl.java:447)
[6/23/16 16:26:16:891 IST] 000000c0 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.application.InstallSchedulerImpl.setupTasks(InstallSchedulerImpl.java:243)
[6/23/16 16:26:16:891 IST] 000000c0 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:303)
[6/23/16 16:26:16:891 IST] 000000c0 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:798)
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks, kusuma

Comment: Why don't you post a code snippet of your script and maybe some debug/print output you've obtained so far.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to deploy multiple war files which depends on status whether deployed application is started or not.

solved the issue ignoring startup of application

```
try{
      if (getDeployementStatus(updateStatus(listener), true).isDeployed()) {
        startApplication(artifact.getAppName(), preferences);
      }
      }catch(Exception e){
          LOGGER.error("error in creating listener for deploy", e);
          return updateStatus(DeployStatus.start_application_failed.name());
      }
```

Thanks,
Kusuma